# CkEditor text align : left plugin = style='text-align:left'

Tags: ckeditor

Hello I am using Ckeditor 4.5.10, I am facing an issue with internal left align plugin. Default left align just remove style attribute from selected tag. What I need, it should be like this `<p style='text-align:left'>test</p>`
however it is doing like this `<p>test</p>`

if someone can help me for this thing

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: Well I removed left align option. because it did not add 'text-align:left' it just removes.

Comment: That's not really an option for me as I need to have the left alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace this function inside ckeditor.js and inline text align left start working:-

```
 g.prototype = {
                        exec: function(a) {
                            var c = a.getSelection(),
                                b = a.config.enterMode;
                            if (c) {
                                for (var h = c.createBookmarks(), d = c.getRanges(), e = this.cssClassName, g, f, k = a.config.useComputedState, k = void 0 === k || k, m = d.length - 1; 0 <= m; m--)
                                    for (g = d[m].createIterator(), g.enlargeBr = b != CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR; f = g.getNextParagraph(b == CKEDITOR.ENTER_P ? "p" : "div");)
                                        if (!f.isReadOnly()) {
                                            f.removeAttribute("align");
                                            f.removeStyle("text-align");                                       
 f.setStyle("text-align", this.value);

                                            //console.log(this.value);
                                            var l = e && (f.$.className = CKEDITOR.tools.ltrim(f.$.className.replace(this.cssClassRegex, ""))),
                                                p = this.state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF && (!k || n(f, !0) != this.value);
                                            e ? p ? f.addClass(e) : l || f.removeAttribute("class") : p && f.setStyle("text-align", this.value)
                                        }
                                a.focus();
                                a.forceNextSelectionCheck();
                                c.selectBookmarks(h)
                            }
                        },
                        refresh: function(a, c) {
                            var b = c.block || c.blockLimit;
                            this.setState("body" != b.getName() && n(b, this.editor.config.useComputedState) == this.value ? CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF)
                        }
                    };
```

> I have included this line in above function:- f.setStyle("text-align",
>   this.value);

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with CKEditor4. I managed to solve it by using a custom build. First of all, you have to be familiar with CKEditor4 custom build process. If you are, you can continue, if not, it is highly recommended to follow the instruction:

[The development repository of CKEditor 4](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev)

If you are here, it means that you are familiar with the custom build process of CKEditor4. In order to address this problem, we should modify the [Justify](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/justify) plugin. You have to edit the file in `plugins/justify/plugin.js` path, and replace

```
} else if ( apply && isAllowedTextAlign ) {
```

With

```
} else {
```

In other words, you have to get rid of the condition of setting the `text-align` CSS style.